# What Psensor data can you read from an intel gpu?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, monitoring, vaapi

On a nvidia gpu with the recommended drivers you can see the folowing values in psensor:

```
gpu temp
gpu utilization 
gpu mem utilization
gpu video decoder utilization
```

But I would like to know what values can be read from an Intel gpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken the Intel GPU will have the same value as the CPU in terms of temperature for psensor data.

This command isn't psensor data but may help you find the info you're looking for.

```
intel_gpu_top
```

Comment: I'm just asking this question out of curiosity. I don't have an Intel cpu with intagrated graphics, so this comand won't work, but thanks for the answer.